# Javascript object, access related keys

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript object:

```
var icecreams = [{
    name: 'vanilla',
    price: 10,
    rating: 3
}, {
    name: 'chocolate',
    price: 4,
    rating: 8
}, {
    name: 'banana',
    price: 1,
    rating: 1
}, {
    name: 'greentea',
    price: 5,
    rating: 7
}, {
    name: 'moosetracks',
    price: 6,
    rating: 2
}, ];
```

I need to access the "related properties" (not sure of the exact terminology) in each section of the object. For example, if I am given the name "vanilla," I need to access a "price" of 10 and "rating" of 3. Is there a way to do this without changing the object's structure? Possibly using `this`?

Comment: So you need to loop over the array. Look at the object, see if it matches, if it does, you have the object you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
var vanilla = icecreams.filter(function(o){
    return o.name === 'vanilla'
});
//As filter return's an array you need to use index thus [0] to access first element of array
console.log(vanilla[0].price);
console.log(vanilla[0].rating);
```

Comment: vanilla is an array not object. it works but like that: vanilla[0].price

Comment: @Przemek, thats what I have used

Answer (score 4):

In ECMAScript 2015 you can find object in your array like this:

```
var vanilla = icecreams.find(o => o.name === 'vanilla')
console.log(vanilla.price);
console.log(vanilla.rating);
```

ES5 analogy:

```
var vanilla = icecreams.reduce(function(r, o) {
    return r || (o.name === 'vanilla' ? o : undefined);
}, undefined);
console.log(vanilla.price);
console.log(vanilla.rating);
```

Comment: The es5 version needs a fix for vanilla.

Answer (score 0):

```
var icecreams = [ {name: 'vanilla', price: 10, rating: 3}, {name: 'chocolate', price: 4, rating: 8}, {name: 'banana', price: 1, rating: 1}, {name: 'greentea', price: 5, rating: 7}, {name: 'moosetracks', price: 6, rating: 2}, ];
var found = {};

for(i in icecreams){
      if(icecreams[i].name == 'vanilla'){
             found = icecreams[i];
             break;
      }
}
console.log('Price: ' + found.price);
console.log('Price: ' + found.rating);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have control over the structure of the variable icecream, I'd uses an oject instead of an array to hold the flavors. This makes it simple to access the values by name.

```
var icecream = {
    vanilla: {price: 10, taring: 3},
    banana: {price: 1, taring: 1},
    greentea: {price: 5, taring: 7},
    moosetracks: {price: 6, taring: 2}
};
```

Or I'd probably adapt them if they came via AJAX (or another dynamic source):

```
//Assume icecream follows your original structure.
function tranformFlavors(flavors) {
    var flavorObj = {};
    flavors.forEach(item){
        flavorObj[item.name] = item;
        delete flavorObj[item.name].name;
    }
    return flavorObj;
}

icecream = transformFlavors(icecream);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using ES5, you can use underscore or lodash for this.

http://underscorejs.org/#find
or
http://underscorejs.org/#filter
or
http://underscorejs.org/#where
or
http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere